# mkdir not working in PHP

Tags: php, mkdir

Have been pulling out my hair for the past 2 hours on this and am sure I am doing something really stupid.

```
<?php
mkdir("blah", 0777);
?>
```

This works through the command line and the folder gets created. But the same thing doesn't work when I try to run it through the browser. Any file permission issues?

Comment: i was stuck with this for a long time, hth someone else. if you are on SELinux there is an extra layer of permissions called "Security Context" which you can see with `ls -alZ`. use something like `chcon system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 public_HTML`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could it possibly be that while running under the command line, the script inherits your permissions, but when running from the browser it doesn't?

In that case you would want to make your directory permissions 'write' for group.

Comment: Haha! 10,000 reputation! Huzzah!

Answer (score 4):

Your web server (apache?) is running as it's own user, and doesn't have permission to write to the directory you're running mkdir in.

Give your web server's user permission to write to the directory by either A) making it Owner, B) adding it to the Group if the Group has write permission, or C) give Everyone write permission (not recommended for most setups).

Comment: Was having the same problem, solved! I created a folder with FTP at first, when using mkdir to create folders inside it didn't work. Deleting the folder and making sure the script creates it solves it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with the `umask`, When PHP is being used as a server module, the umask is restored when each request is finished.

```
$old = umask(0); 
mkdir($path,0777); 
umask($old);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make `mkdir` code run in Linux you need to add permission `a+rwx` to this file by `sudo chmod a+w [file/path]` or

```
sudo chmod a+rwx [file/path]
```

Comment: Please note, there are security concerns with your approach