# In reference to old forum mkdir not working through php

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I have few query in reference to old forum 
 [mkdir() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215849/mkdir-not-working-in-php)

my webserver is running as daemon and I am running php scripts from /home/gpsr/webserver/cgidocs/username/website. suppose username is thind in this case. thind has pemission to write in /home/gpsr/webserver/cgidocs/thind directory.(as granted by admin. of server). but do not have  sudo permission.

OS:ubuntu12

Here I am facing the same problem as mention in above linked forum. 
Daemon (or php script running from above mention directory) cann't create folder. (error: permission denied). How I can solve this problem.

Comment: Are you really sure the process owner is the account "thind"? Usually scripts inside a webserver environment are executed under the account the webserver itself runs under.

Comment: No, you misunderstood. Webserver process is executed by daemon ( from "who am I" command). But I kept all php files in thind user directory.

Comment: That is exactly what I would have expected. That means that the folder must be writable for the account `daemon`, not for the account `thind`!